# How to change a hook inside text input in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In this basic example of typescript react I am trying to change the state name by a user input inside a pop-up.

My pop-up is a class whose name is `ConfirmDialog`

When I type something in the input, it goes out of input focus. I have to click on the input field again to continue.

This is the part of my `confirmDialog` : ( Confirmdialog.tsx )

```
export const useConfirmDialog = (
  props: ConfirmDialogProps
): [() => void, () => ReactElement] => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  function toggleDialog() {
    setShow((show) => !show);
  }

  const Dialog = () => (
    <ConfirmDialogModal
      key="confirmDialog"
      {...props}
      open={show}
      toggleDialog={toggleDialog}
    />
  );
  return [toggleDialog, Dialog];
};

export interface ConfirmDialogModalProps extends ConfirmDialogProps {
  open: boolean;
  toggleDialog: () => void;
}

export type ConfirmDialogProps = {
  titleKey: string;
  messageKey?: string;
  noCancelButton?: boolean;
  confirmButtonDisabled?: boolean;
  deleteCheckBox?: boolean;
  cancelButtonLabel?: string;
  continueButtonLabel?: string;
  continueButtonVariant?: ButtonVariant;
  variant?: ModalVariant;
  inputArea?: ReactElement;
  onConfirm: () => void;
  onCancel?: () => void;
  children?: ReactNode;
};
```

And this part is the field where I want the user to enter a value.

```js
const [toggleCloneDialog, CloneConfirm] = useConfirmDialog({
  titleKey: 'roles:cloneRole',
  messageKey: deleteMessage,
  continueButtonLabel: 'roles:clone',
  inputArea: (
    <TextInput
      type="text"
      id="kc-name"
      name="name"
      value={clonedRoleName}
      onChange={(clonedRoleName) =>
        onChangeHandler({
          target: { value: clonedRoleName, name: 'name' },
        })
      }
    />
  ),
  continueButtonVariant: ButtonVariant.primary,
  onConfirm: async () => {
    console.log('s');
    clone();
  },
});
```

And the last one is `onChangeHandler` method :

```js
const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  setClonedRoleName(value);
  console.log(clonedRoleName);
};
```

This is a summary picture of my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your focus gets lost because the whole subtree from the `Dialog` downwards gets thrown away and inserted again into the DOM by the reconciler. This is caused by your re-definition of the `Dialog` component inside your custom hook. The identity changes with every render, and therefore can never survive. See this code of yours:

```
const Dialog = () => (
    <ConfirmDialogModal
      key="confirmDialog"
      {...props}
      open={show}
      toggleDialog={toggleDialog}
    />
  );
```

The `Dialog` constant is a completely new function on every render.

I recommend a completely different approach. Not using a custom hook to create a `Dialog` component on the fly. I would inline the `Dialog` into the place where you need it, and assign a `ref`; with this ref you can then call `dialog.toggle()` to get the desired behavior. The state of the dialog would still be inside the dialog component. This is called an `imperative handle` and it is mostly overlooked by react devs (instead of the more widely known `declarative` way of settings props).
Here is a code sketch of what I have in mind:

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useState, useRef } from 'react';

const Dialog = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ toggle: () => setShow(_ => !_) }), []);

  return (<ConfirmDialogModal
      key="confirmDialog"
      {...props}
      open={show}
      toggleDialog={() => setShow(_ => !_)}
    />);
});


const MyApp = () => {
  // ...
  
  const dialog = useRef(null);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dialog.current.toggle()} />
      // ...
      <Dialog ref={dialog} ... />
    </div>
  );
};
```